# Script to draw pairs of numbers linearly in python

Tags: python, math, visualization

Say one has a list of 3 pairs of numbers:

[(100,200), (110, 190), (90, 210)]

I would like to write a script to automatically (for this set or any set of numbers) to draw such lines; the x refers to relative positions of numbers in each set and say the maximum length is 50 (i.e., sum of all - and x in each line); the point is to be to scale.

----x-----------------x----

-----x---------------x-----

---x-------------------x---

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? This is simple math btw. and I'm sure you can do it, if you give it a try. You obviously want to solve it by others…

Comment: Not really, something that is easy math for person A may not be for be for person B. I tried setting a length 50, so I thought to divide by that; but that is not correct because 10,0000 value will give 400 which is out of bounds. I thought to find the min of the left values and substract that, again same problem. If it is easy math wasn't easy to just help rather than mock?

Comment: I do not mock, but you could at least tell about your math problem, and what you tried etc. One question though: you are plotting eg. 100 and 200 in the first line, why is there a margin on the left/right side?

Comment: oh yes, the first one is the (100,200); the third is 90,210 and thus theoretically 90 should be at position 1 on line 3 there but its nice to see some slack before but that is a technicality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is pretty close to what you're looking for:

```
number_pairs = [(100,200), (110, 190), (90, 210)]

max_width = 50
min_value = min([i for j in number_pairs for i in j])
max_value = max([i for j in number_pairs for i in j])
step = max_width / float(max_value - min_value)

for num1, num2 in number_pairs:
    line = list('-' * max_width)
    pos1 = int((num1 - min_value + 1) * step - 1)
    pos2 = int((num2 - min_value + 1) * step - 1)
    line[pos1] = 'x'
    line[pos2] = 'x'
    print(''.join(line))
```

Comment: I guess you were right, it was easy math it just did not occur to me :( thank you for your help!

Comment: So this worked great just what I wanted but my problem is that it is not sensitive for large numbers say for this set:

number_pairs = [(1265465,5023553), (1265347, 5023453), (1265365, 5023453), (1265435, 5021236), (1265435, 5021256), (1265455, 5021236), (1265450, 5022394)]

I tried Log10() each value before it did the rest of the script but did not help; the left side the x are on top of one another. Any suggestion to normalize big numbers?

Comment: I guess for such big numbers, there is no easy way to visualise the differences using such a big granularity, since the aberrations are quite low.